# Excel: Textbox, buttons jumbling up

Tags: excel, vba

I made a form on excel sheet and added text boxes and buttons. The problem that i am facing is that , few of my colleagues when they open the file on their computer ,for some reason all the items are displaced from their orignal positions. When i open it in mine , it is working fine.

Does anyone have a clue why this is happening?

Thanks